# What (if anything) is wrong with my swapfile question regarding being off-topic?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905404/dedicated-swap-drive-without-using-a-drive-letter

I see this has been downvoted-without-comment, and also has two close votes for being off-topic.

How is it any more off-topic than many of the other questions I see tagged with [swapfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swapfile)?  Is there some subtlety I'm missing? Just looking at the top half dozen, it seems that "I need to <do something> concerning the swapfile or pagefile for <some specific reason>" is acceptable for this SE.

If it's a matter of "we've not noticed or gotten around to flagging the others yet" then I wonder why the tag exists. Note that "The swapfile tag has no usage guidance," so I have to take the existing posts as implicit description of what it's *for*.

Comment: The existence of a tag does not mean a question is on topic according to current guidelines. Many tags (and previous questions) existed before other [se] sites existed, but once those other sites were created are no longer on topic. Your question as stated is more suitable for [su], as it has nothing to do with programming and therefore does not meet the current SO guidelines. You should always check the site's [help] before posting to make sure you meet the **current** site guidelines. It's not a matter of "the others haven't been flagged yet"; it's a matter of "guidelines evolve".

Comment: 3 questions are contemporary with mine (with no close votes!), though I do see that before that it was last active in July.

Comment: The site is huge, there aren't enough close voters at all times, not everything that should be closed is actually closed.

Answer (score 7):

Lousy tags exist because tag cleanup tooling is *sorely* lacking, and there's a ton of built-up cruft. That's an area of the system where proper scaling was not designed in originally, and if anything, the problems are probably getting worse.

Broken window questions exist because it's often hard to get enough eyes to stamp all of them out (and because sometimes, those who *do* notice do not have enough perspicacity to close/flag appropriately).

But fundamentally, a question about proper configuration of general OS settings is **blatantly**, irredeemably off-topic on a site about practical programming problems. It has no more to do with programming than a question about fixing a drowned keyboard, or one about flashing BIOS, or one about useful guidelines for arranging your chair and desk to avoid RSI. All of which might be on topic at some reasonable SE site… one that is *not* SO.

Comment: That makes sense.  I might add a description to the tag wiki on this particular one, once I'm suee I understand that properly.  Do they not migrate questions here? If the "reason" was "belongs on another SE" I'm not seeing any indication, while on Worldbuilding that shows up as a comment even though they don't have it set up to auto-migrate to specific sites yet.

Comment: SO actually has a close reason that *does* and a close reason that *doesn't* migrate to SU; some questions don't necessarily meet the high standards for migration. In particular, four out of five close voters have to select migration for that to go through; otherwise it's just closed.